# Calling FormMouseDown in Delphi

Tags: delphi, mouseevent

I have a thumbnail of a picture. I have written code to redraw this image in Delphi as soon as the user clicks this button. However the requirement is user can click the thumbnail and can click anywhere in the form to create the image.

For instance lets say I have a thumbnail of a circle image, now user shall click this thumbnail and click somewhere in the form and the circle should appear.

For this I came to know we need to use

```
TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject;Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;X, Y: Integer) ;
```

I didn't  get how to send X,Y coordinates to this?
Ex:

```
procedure TMDIChild.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject;Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Canvas.Ellipse(x-20,y-20,x+20,y+20) ;
end;
```

Should draw an ellipse(circle) when the left click button is clicked somewhere in the form after clicking the thumbnail.
But x,y should be current mouse pointer and how do I get the current mouse pointer after the user has clicked the thumbnail?

I really appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Giridhar.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention about the platform: Its windows using Delphi.

Comment: You seem to be understanding things incorrectly. *You* don't call `FormMouseDown`; it's an event that is automatically called (through Windows message processing) when the *user* clicks the mouse button. There should never be a need to call it yourself.

Comment: procedure TMDIChild.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
Canvas.MoveTo(X, Y);{ set pen position }
end;


procedure TMDIChild.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
Canvas.LineTo(X, Y);{ draw line from PenPos to (X, Y) }
end;

Is my understanding right? If these two procedures combine then it should draw a line at the mouse clicked position?

Comment: You missed what I said. I didn't say don't **use** `OnMouseDown` - I said you don't **call** it yourself. But no, the code in your last comment is not how to do what you're asking to do. Read Warren and David's answers for the proper way to draw the line (in the `OnPaint` event and nowhere else).

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
Mouse.CursorPos.x and Mouse.CursorPos.y
```

and if you would like the change the origin of coords (screen or form) you should use  `ScreenToClient()` or `ClientToScreen()`.

Comment: `Mouse.CursorPos` is the mouse position **now**. The coords passed to the event handler are the coords when the mouse went down. So `Mouse.CursorPos` is wrong here. The coords passed to the event handler are client coords.

Comment: I am not getting the mouse cursor. I tried using it and it is drawing the figure at center of the form. I read something like this in delphi developers guide which uses the code procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
Canvas.TextOut(X, Y, 'Here!');{ write text at (X, Y) }
end;
But even this is not responding to the mouse event if I click on the form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the problem but I can see one thing wrong. You can't expect to paint to the form canvas in a mouse down event and hope that what you draw will remain. Painting in Windows simply does not work that way. You need to paint the form in response to a `WM_PAINT` message.

There is no persistent drawing surface associated with a window. When a window needs to be painted the system posts a `WM_PAINT` message to your message queue. You are then obliged to paint the current state of the window.

The simplest way to achieve that in your case will be to paint to an off screen bitmap in response to mouse messages and then display that bitmap as part of the paint cycle. You can access the paint cycle by putting a `TPaintBox` on your form and handling the `OnPaint` event. In that event simply draw the bitmap to the paint box canvas.

You'll need to make the paint box repaint itself whenever you update the bitmap. Do this by calling the `Invalidate` method of the paint box.

I recommend reading Petzold's book [Programming Windows](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/) to get a thorough understanding of how painting works in Windows.

Comment: Hi David, yes that is why I am using canvas graphics tool in Delphi. Now I just want the current mouse position wherever the user clicks on the form.

Comment: This comment makes little sense to me. You can't paint to form canvas in a mouse down event. If you want the coords then X and Y do the job. Your question was not "what are the current X and Y coords". When you say current what do you mean? The coords when the mouse went down, or the coords when the event is handled. When the mouse went down is what you should be asking for and those coords are the X and Y parameters to the mouse down event. In Sender client coords.

Comment: Current position means where the mouse went down. First the user will click on the thumbnail and triggers the event. Now user can move his mouse anywhere in the form and click anywhere. I want this co-ordinates where he/she clicks to be passed into my drawing function. So that the image can be drawn at that point where he/she clicked.

Comment: X and Y parameters of mouse event is what you need.

Comment: Yes David, I just need those x,y parameters

Comment: @user - When the user clicks on the form after he clicks on an image, isn't the FormMouseDown event triggered again?

Comment: Hello Sertac, Ya I was thinking that FormMouseDown event should be triggered inorder to draw that image at that location. In other words, I thought to get the current X,Y position of the user click on the form I need FormMouseDown. All I need is current(click on form) X,Y parameter of the mouse click.

Comment: @user - I don't see anything wrong with your thought. If it's not working that way there's something else blocking the event handler to be triggered, but it's impossible to know what with the supplied information.

Answer (score 0):

Drop a paintbox onto your form, and write some code in the paintbox control  OnPaint event like this:

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
var
 pb:TPaintBox;
 h,w:Integer;
begin
    pb := TPaintBox(Sender);
    h := pb.Height;
    w := pb.Width;
    pb.Canvas.Ellipse( 10, 10, w-10, h-10 );
end;
```

There is no way to draw from FormMouseDown directly.  So add some code in FormMouseDown to capture the co-ordinates, store them in a variable, and then invalidate your paintbox control (Paintbox1.Invalidate) and the ellipse will get drawn by the paintbox control. (You can put a paintbox on top of another control, if you need to, for instance).

Comment: Hi Warren, I am using canvas graphics with Delphi. Just I need to capture the current mouse co-ordinates and pass it to another procedure. How to capture the current mouse co-ordinates?

Comment: You are totally confused it seems.  The X,Y parameters in the MouseDown event are exactly the values you want. Yes. You said that's what you want, and then you said how do I get them? Well, when the mouse gets clicked down, take those X,Y values and STORE THEM IN A VARIABLE SOMEWHERE.  If the mouse position is needed at some time other than when you press the mouse button, look at the MouseMove event instead of MouseDown.